# @font-face with a TTF collection rejected by Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use a `.ttc` font collection in a Laravel project.
I used it like this.

```css
@font-face {
     font-family: Avenir Next;
     src: url('{{ asset("fonts/Avenir Next.ttc") }}');
}
```

but Firefox won't load the font. Instead, there is an error in the console:

`downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Avenir Next" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: http://localhost:8000/fonts/Avenir%20Next.ttc`

or, as an image:

[image]

To solve this problem, I converted font to ttf or oft, but converted fonts is different with origin font.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox rejected your font file because it didn't recognise the TTC font collection format. It appears Firefox [doesn't yet support font collections in `@font-face`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1529652).

For browsers that do support collections, you'll need to use a fragment identifier to select a specific font from the TTC collection. The [CSS3 Font specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-fonts/#font-face-src-loading) states the fragment identifier should be the PostScript name; use the `fc-scan` command-line tool from the `fontconfig` package to get the postscript names from a TTC file:

```
$ fc-scan filename.ttc | grep postscriptname
```

`fontconfig` is [Open Source software from freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/), find it in your Linux package manager, or, on MacOS use homebrew to install it.

You may want to tell browsers that the URL points to a font collection by adding `format(collection)` after the URL, in which case Firefox won't even download the file as it knows, without downloading, that it won't be able to use the fonts from the collection. Not that Firefox [yet supports the `format()` tag](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_font-face_src_format_keyword) on URLs, but we can hope.

So, for any browsers that do support font collections in TTC files, the syntax is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Avenir Next;
    // assumption: the PostScript name for the specific font to pick is
    // Avenir-Next-Regular. Use fc-scan to find the correct fragment ID here.
    src: url('{{ asset("fonts/Avenir Next.ttc") }}#Avenir-Next-Regular') format(collection);
}
```

Since Firefox doesn't yet support this, you are better off converting the TTC collection to individual fonts; preferably WOFF and WOFF2 for the broadest support. There are online tools that can do this for you; you should get *multiple* fonts, and you'll need to select the one with the right weight from this to use.

The `src:` property is a *list* of options, the browser will pick the first supported. So you could keep the TTC file for browsers that support collections; these will download a single collection that can be shared between `@font-face` definitions, and then list WOFF2 and WOFF urls after that:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Avenir Next;
    src:
        url('{{ asset("fonts/Avenir Next.ttc") }}#Avenir-Next-Regular') format(collection),
        url('{{ asset("fonts/Avenir Next Regular.woff2" }}') format(woff2),
        url('{{ asset("fonts/Avenir Next Regular.woff" }}') format(woff);
}
```

If there are browsers that support font collections, using a TTF collection would have the benefit of limiting the number of requests you'd need to support multiple fonts, plus the combined fonts can be stored more efficiently if they share glyph information.

The final caveat is that I don't know what browsers do support this; there is no information on this on CanIUse.com. I have [suggested CanIUse could provide this info](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/6566).

Answer (score 1):

The file `.ttc` is a font collection, while `@font-face` is used to specify one single font that should be used by the browser. You'd need to extract single font asset out of that collection and then use that said font in `@font-face`.
For example like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
   url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Comment: See the [`@font-face` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), you can use PostScript names in the URL fragment to identify a specific font in a collection. Firefox simply doesn't yet support collections.